# DiffEq Analytic at a Point Conceptual Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In Diff Eq I'm at the point where we are discussing functions that are analytic at certain points, and singular points.

I'm trying to understand these conceptually.

My book says:  A function $f$ is said to be analytic at a point $a$ if it can be represented by a power series $x-a$ with either a positive or an infinite radius of convergence.

So if I'm to break this down, does it simply mean that the function $f$ must converge but must also be a function involving at least one variable in order to be analytic?

I'm having some trouble finding the right criteria to be able to differentiate between analytic and non-analytic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An analytic function is a function for which both the taylor series exists (so the function has to be infinitely differentiable), and the taylor series for the function converges TO the function.  An example of a smooth yet not analytic function is $f(x)=e^{-\frac 1 {x}}$ for $x>0$,  $f(x)=0$ for $x \le 0$. You can check (link for details here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) that this function is infinitely differentiable, but when you plug in 0, you get all derivatives are 0, so at the origin this converges to the 0 function, not the function itself.

As a side note,  things get much nicer when we move to the complex plane.   There's a result that says that if a function is differentiable in a neighborhood of a point, then it's analytic in that same neighborhood.  (That only holds over $\mathbb C$, not $\mathbb R$ though)

Comment: Thanks Alan.  So when we say a function is analytic at a specific point, how does that factor in?

Comment: A function is analytic at $x_0$ if $f(x_0)$ is what the taylor series converges to

Comment: Thanks Alan -- one more question, where does the "singular" concept fit in?

Comment: Singularities are where a function fails to be analytic,  and usually isn't even defined.  Look up "singularities"